# Changing the width of parent element on Hover over a specific Icon area only

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I am creating a Navigation menu containing four icons but I can't get my head around how to achieve it.

Checkout my desired outcome:
[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH1xn.png)

I tried,

```
navIcon:hover
 {
    background-size: 50px; border-radius: 20px;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take a moment to review [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and specifically how to create a [minimally, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help you without some code. :-)

Comment: Instead if `background-size` use `font-size: 50px; `

Answer (score 0):

first I think it's better if you can refer "[how do I ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

If you are using an icon, use

```
font-size:50px
```

instead of,

```
background-size:50px
```

or,

You can transform the size when hovering to scale up.

```css
div{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

div:hover{
    transform: scale(2,3);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

use,

```
transform: scale(2,3)
```

The above code will increase the  element to two times its original width and three times its original height when hovering.

[html](/questions/tagged/html)[css](/questions/tagged/css)[animation](/questions/tagged/animation)[transform](/questions/tagged/transform)[scale](/questions/tagged/scale)